# set authentication token in http header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been following the railscast on how to set authentication tokens
http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast

I have setup my app very well and it uses the authenticate_or_request_with_http_token method to get the token.

My problem is that I have a next app that needs to set the token in the header.
Something like:

```
uri = URI.parse(full_url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'this_is_a_test_key'
response = http.request(request)
```

The above code is getting an access denied. I know it is easy to set custom ones like X-CUSTOM-TOKEN, but how do I set the default one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The header name isn't `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` and you have to set it like this set it as:

```
request['authorization'] = "Token token=#{token}"
```

To be able to use the `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` method.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [ActionController::HttpAuthentication](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication.html) module, e.g.

```
user = 'whatever'
pass = 'you-like'
auth = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user, pass)
request.headers['Authorization'] = auth
```

Similarly for a token, e.g.

```
token = 'whatever-it-is'
auth = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(token)
request.headers['Authorization'] = auth
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work.

In Rails 4 it should be `request.authorization`  not `request['authorization']`