# How to make a HTTP GET request in ruby with Authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm working to download a file via the Google Drive API. The docs show the following example below as seen here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

How can I make that request with Ruby?

Comment: I think you may find your answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481164/set-authentication-token-in-http-header) question.

Comment: And you should also review their quick start guide. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/ruby I'm not sure you can authorize that easily, with a single get request.